# How to query DyDx liquidations from ethereum blockchain?

Tags: nodejs, exchanges

As far as I understand, all the exchanges like DyDx, Uniswap, Sushiswap etc. are actually contracts deployed on blockchain. So their data should be accessible to anyone having the chain downloaded. (please correct me if I am mistaken)

I am trying to query the current liquidations from DyDx exchange in real time using node.js but I am having trouble actually finding any good documentation how to do it. I have geth installed and fully synced available and I can connect to it with node.js but I do not know how to query the data.

I was trying to find the contract responsible for this mechanism and dig into the code itself but I did not find anything either. Their docs mainly speak about mechanism itself and provide examples for python / typescript, which uses some npm but connects to their API, which I do not want. I found this on etherscan: https://etherscan.io/accounts/label/dydx to list out every contract dydx is related to but I am not sure where to look.

Comment: Check out mevexplorer.com they’ve got all that sorts data